# Ruby on Rails update user attributes without password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, passwords, bcrypt

I am trying to create a means for a user to update their details without a password. I am using BCrypt with `has_secure_password` in my user model so that when a user signs up or changes password, the `password` and `password_confirmation` fields are checked to match before being saved to `password_digest`. I also have the following validation for setting a password:

`validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }`

As is users are able to update their password fine (so long as it meets the validations by being at least 5 characters long). But if a user tries to update their details (I have separate views/forms for updating password and updating other non-required attributes) then it gives an error saying "Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 5 characters)"

I have read through a lot of previous stackoverflow questions/answers and the closest I've got is adding `, allow_blank: true` to the end of the validation. This pretty much works as I want it to as BCrypt handles the validation if the password is blank so when signing up a user can't give a blank password, and users are able to change their details without a password. However when updating a password if the user gives a blank password then something weird happens. The blank password doesn't save (As it shouldn't since because BCrypt still needs a matching password and password_confirmation, which can't be blank), however the controller acts as though it does and passes the notice "password updated.". Here is my code in the controller:

```
def update
  if Current.user.update(password_params)
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Password updated."
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

private

def password_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

I am particularly confused as to why `Current.user.update(password_params)` seems to be returning true (hence redirecting to the root path and passing the notice mentioned before) but the password definitely hasn't been updated. I have checked by logging out and back in again with the previous password and a blank password does not allow me to log in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like these, your best chance is to go to the source code of [has_secure_password](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5aaaa1630ae9a71b3c3ecc4dc46074d678c08d67/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L61). You will find following code there:

```rb
        define_method("#{attribute}=") do |unencrypted_password|
          if unencrypted_password.nil?
            self.public_send("#{attribute}_digest=", nil)
          elsif !unencrypted_password.empty?
            instance_variable_set("@#{attribute}", unencrypted_password)
            cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
            self.public_send("#{attribute}_digest=", BCrypt::Password.create(unencrypted_password, cost: cost))
          end
        end
```

when you call `has_secure_password` this code will create setter where `attribute` is `password`. It will dynamically create following method:

```rb
        def password=(unencrypted_password)
          if unencrypted_password.nil?
            self.password_digest = nil
          elsif !unencrypted_password.empty?
            @password = unencrypted_password
            cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
            self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(unencrypted_password, cost: cost))
          end
        end
```

This method then gets called when you assign attributes to your model:

```rb
Current.user.update(password_params)
```

As you can see newly defined method contains simple condition with two branches:

1. If you set `password` to `nil` it will delete the `password_digest`
2. If you set `password` to nonempty string it will store password hash to `password_digest` attribute

That is all. When your user sends empty password this method decides to do nothing and ignores the empty string, it doesn't get automatically assigned as empty password. Model pretty much completely ignores input (if `password_confirmation` is also empty), nothing gets saved, no validation is violated which means that `Current.user.update(password_params)` returns success and your controller proceeds with "Password updated." branch.

Now, when you know about this behaviour what can you do about it?

---

Let's say you model looks like this

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

And you want your validation to work in two cases

1. When new user is created
2. When users update their password

First case is easy, as you mentioned in your question if you use `allow_blank: true` instead of `presence: true` validation is handled by `has_secure_password` if password is empty and if it is not, password will proceed through the validation.

But than we get to other requirements:

- User has to be able update other attributes then just password
- We still want to validate password if it gets updated

These two requirements rule out the `presence: true` part of the validation, it cannot be there. Same thing applies to `allow_blank: true`. In this case you probably want to use conditional validation:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 5 }, if: :password_required?

private

  def password_required?
    password.present?
  end
end
```

This code ensures that validation is executed every time user fills in the password. It doesn't matter if it's `create` or `update` action.

Now to the last thing.

**What if user leaves empty password**.
From your question I suppose you want to show validation error if user sends empty password. From description above `User` model doesn't know that it should validate the password at all. You have to tell your model about it eg. like this:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 5 }, if: :password_required?

  def enforce_password_validation
    @enforce_password_validation = true
  end

private

  def password_required?
    @enforce_password_validation || password.present?
  end
end
```

Now you could use it like this in your controller:

```rb
  def update
    user = Current.user
    user.enforce_password_validation

    if user.update(password_params)
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Password updated."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

private

  def password_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

Now validation should fail even if user submits empty password.

Comment: Wow thank you for such a detailed answer! That works exactly as I want, and the explanation was great in helping me understand what was going on.

Comment: Awesome, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same configuration as the first answer.
This my **User.rb model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: :password_required?
  validates :password_confirmation, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: :password_required?
  has_secure_password

private

  def password_required?
    false || password.present?
  end
end
```

It worked adding **false** at the beginning of the method.
Now, in my controller, I have this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def confirm_email
    user = User.find_by(token: params[:token])
    user.update(is_confirmed?: true)
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You've confirmed your account"
  end
  ...
end
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

For the validation of the password in your model try this instead :

validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }, on: :create

This line mean that the validation will be only call on :create method not :update anymore. So that you can remove the allow_bank and your update password will work fine

Comment: No this doesn't work for two reasons. Firstly it allows passwords to be updated to less than 5 characters. Secondly, the notice saying "password updated." still gets displayed after entering a blank password. (to be clear the password isn't saved as blank, only the notice shows as though it has).

Comment: Yes this is definitely weird. Can you please try this `Current.user.update!(password_params)` to see if the Update method will raise an exception. Just put the "!" after the Update method like I did.